# CSS giving different look and feel in Chrome and IE

Tags: css

I developed a website in drupal. But there is one last problem before I can put this production.

URL for my test page is [test url here](http://techmasti.forwardsfarm.com/)

Let me explain the problem in images.

CSS looks good chrome and below screen shot of image when loaded in Google Chrome.
[chrome screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/chromen.png/)

When I load the page in IE8 there is huge space between post title which is html header2 and teaser which is html paragraph.[IE8 screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/705/14741408.png/)

Can you help me remove this space between teaser and post title.

Comment: you could try removing the margin from the p-elements?

Comment: You have a P element inside a DIV with display:inline. I'm not sure if the behaviour of margins and paddings is defined in that case. By the way, do you really need 20 divs nested inside one another?

Comment: yeah there seems to be a lot of unnecessary defined div tags with no CSS hooks, im guessing its adapted from another theme? The same result appears in Firefox on osx. Removing display:inline in .field-item should do it.

Comment: @ptriek tried that. But without the margin there is still some extra space between post title and teaser. Somehow the paragragh is floated bit lower than the thumbnail image. But I am not able figure the css thats doing this only in IE.

Comment: @MrLister removing the p elements inline seems to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
field-item{
display:inline;
}
```

remove the display property.

*thought id post the solution rather than in the comments*

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
display:inline;
```

and / or

```
padding-left: 5px;
```

from `.field-item`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it on IE 9.. And this is a bit of a guess but I tried to alter the p-tags margin-top to -15px so I guess that IE forces styling to the p-tag.. I think I would try to change it to a div.

```
<div style="vertical-align: top; background-color: red;" class="content">
    <div class="field field-name-field-thumbnail field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><a href="/content/sun-setting-rio"><img alt="" src="http://techmasti.forwardsfarm.com/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/5657048733_9ecb8bff8e_b.jpg" typeof="foaf:Image"></a></div></div></div><div class="field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div style="margin-top: 0px;" class="field-item even" property="content:encoded"><p style="margin-top: 0px;">We start with customizing the appearance using an existing theme. You may be surprised how customizable an existing theme can be simply by changing a few settings. From there we discuss ways to make your own theme based on an existing theme, and then show you how to tweak it through the use of CSS stylesheets.</p>
</div></div></div>  </div>
```

hope it's helpful eventhough its a guess :-)